# C# failed to update a record in msaccess database

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
 Sqlcon.Open();
```

hi my update wont work when i run this script, this is the first time i use MSACCESS as database, please help me how to Update, Thanks

```
var _query = "update [Inventory_tbl] set [Item Name] = ?, [Description] = ?, [Price] = ?, [Stock] = ?  where [Item Code] = ?";

var cmd = new OleDbCommand(_query, Sqlcon) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Item Code]", getitemcode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Item Name]", getitemname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Description]", getdesc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Price]", getprice);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Stock]", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myStock) - Convert.ToInt32(getquantity)));
var ctr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Sqlcon.Close();
MessageBox.Show(ctr.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What exception or error message you get? What is your `Sqlcon` looks like? And you don't need `CommandType.Text`. It is by default.

Comment: public OleDbConnection Sqlcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.\NSH.accdb"); this is my sqlcon

Comment: it didnt have an error but it is not updating my record

Comment: And you are sure the `item code` you enter can be found in the DB? If you remove the `where`, does it update then?

Comment: Item Code Item Name Description Price Stock
1 Patola Large Php15.00 100
2 Kalabasa Medium Php20.00 100

Comment: Item Code,Item Name,Description,Price,Stock

Comment: @JohnMarkQuizon: check Soners answer. He is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS-Access, parameters added to your `OleDbCommand` the **order** you declare them.

For your case, you add `getitemcode` value to your `Item Name` column which I think it belongs on `Item Code` at the end.

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID =` ?

> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

I think your code should be like;

```
var _query = "update [Inventory_tbl] set [Item Name] = ?, [Description] = ?, [Price] = ?, [Stock] = ?  where [Item Code] = ?";

var cmd = new OleDbCommand(_query, Sqlcon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Item Name]", getitemname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Description]", getdesc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Price]", getprice);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Stock]", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myStock) - Convert.ToInt32(getquantity)));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Item Code]", getitemcode);
var ctr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Sqlcon.Close();
MessageBox.Show(ctr.ToString());
}
```

Comment: (For your case, you add getitemcode value to your Item Name column which I think it belongs on Item Code at the end.) wow it works!!! thank you very much!! soner :)

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Item Name]", getitemname);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Description]", getdesc);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Price]", getprice);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Stock]", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myStock) - Convert.ToInt32(getquantity)));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Item Code]", getitemcode);

Comment: @JohnMarkQuizon You are quite welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider to accept it as an answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: i have got an internet problem lately , sir thanks you again :)